# Dynamic Subject in a Visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce, email, visualforce-template

This is my Visual force email template :

**Controller**

```
public class casetemplate{

    public id accountid{get;set;}

    public list<case> getcases(){

        List<case> caselist= [SELECT CaseNumber,Description,ContactEmail,ContactMobile,ContactPhone,CreatedDate,OwnerId FROM Case where accountid =:accountid ];
        return caselist;
    }
}
```

**Component**

```
<apex:component controller="casetemplate" access="global">
    <apex:attribute name="accttid" type="id"  description="Id of account" assignTo="{!accountid}"/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Case Number</td>
            <td>Case Description</td>
        </tr>
        <apex:repeat value="{!cases}" var="c">
            <tr>
                <td>{!c.casenumber}</td>
                <td>{!c.description}</td>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
</apex:component>
```

**Email Template**

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Case Description :Case.description    Created Date :    Owner :" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="account">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        <br>This is the list of cases for your account {!relatedto.name}</br>
        <br><c:Casecontacttemplate accttid="{!relatedto.id}"/></br>

    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

I want my email subject to  dynamically populate Case Description :   ,Created Date :    ,Owner : ,fields from case .So this is what my subject of email template should look like

Case Description : Issue with EMail Template   ,Created Date :5/5/2017    ,Owner :Natasha williams

Comment: I also tried this way <messaging:emailTemplate subject="Case Description :{!relatedto.account.Cases__r.description } " recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="account">  and this too <messaging:emailTemplate subject="Case Description :{!relatedto.Cases__r.description } " recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="account"> but nothing helped

Comment: Okay ,I just figured it out , Posting the updated code here so that it could help someone else :-)              <messaging:emailTemplate subject="Case Description :{!relatedto.Description }   Created Date : {!relatedto.CreatedDate}   Owner :{!relatedto.OwnerId}" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="account">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<br>This is the list of cases for your account {!relatedto.name}</br>
<br><c:Casecontacttemplate accttid="{!relatedto.id}"/></br>
<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Cases}">

</apex:repeat>

</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>

Comment: can you try pasting your last comment as an answer, and as for your first comment, update your question so it includes it, this is not a very good use for the comment ssection

Answer (score 4):

Okay ,I just figured it out , Posting the updated code here so that it could help someone else :-)

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Case Description :{!relatedto.Description } Created Date : {!relatedto.CreatedDate} Owner :{!relatedto.OwnerId}" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="account"> <messaging:htmlEmailBody > <br>This is the list of cases for your account {!relatedto.name}</br> <br><c:Casecontacttemplate accttid="{!relatedto.id}"/></br> <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Cases}"> </apex:repeat> </messaging:htmlEmailBody> </messaging:emailTemplate>
```